# How do I rotate a UIImage and then rotate it back in reverse?

Tags: swift, uikit, cgaffinetransform

I have a UITableViewCell with a UIImageView. When the user taps on the cell in my table view, `cell.isExpanded.toggle()` is called which rotates the image.

Right now it rotates from 0 to 180, clockwise, but when tapped again, it rotates 180 to 0, also clockwise.

**How do I get it to rotate 180 to 0 counter-clockwise when the value is false?**

```
class TVCell: UITableViewCell {

    var isExpanded = false {
        didSet {
            rotateImage(isExpanded)
        }
    }

    let iv = UIImageView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(iv)
        iv.center.x = 33
        iv.center.y = 6
        iv.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func rotateImage(_ val: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            if val {
                self.iv.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
            } else {
                self.iv.transform = .identity
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `CGFloat.pi` and `-CGFloat.pi` animates in same position.

Counter clockwise rotation can be done by  `-(CGFloat.pi * 0.999)`

```
self.iv.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:-(CGFloat.pi * 0.999))
```

Answer (score 0):

This was what I found is simplest and works best

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    let rotationAngle: CGFloat = val ? .pi : (-.pi * 2)
    self.iv.transform = .init(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
}, completion: nil)
```